# Restricting the number of checkboxes that can be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to restrict the number of checkboxes that can be selected to 3. The code below works but I would like to restrict it to the div class `pricing-levels-3` containing the checkboxes.

HTML:

```
 <div class="pricing-levels-3">
      <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
      <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
    alert("allowed only 3");
}
})
```

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/ANNF9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANNF9/62/)

```
$('.pricing-levels-3 input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
   if ($('.pricing-levels-3 input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
        alert("allowed only 3");
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you should read about [**Selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

```
$('.pricing-levels-3 > input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
   if ($('.pricing-levels-3 > input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
        alert("allowed only 3");
   }
})
```